# Prove the Gödel theorem using the Busy Beaver function

Tags: logic, arithmetic, computability, turing-machines, incompleteness

Assume we know the following for a  fact: $L$ is an arithmetic language and contains a formula (abbreviated “$BB(x_i, x_j)$”) expressing the Busy Beaver function, i.e. $BB(k, n)$ is true if and only if the productivity of the most productive (one-symbol) Turing Machine with $k$ states or fewer is $n$.

Prove Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem.

My attempt:
For the sake of contradiction, let $M$ be a Turing machine that decides the truth of sentences of $L$. Then by the fact above, we can use $M$'s program to construct a Turing machine $M^B$ that computes the Busy Beaver function. But the latter is not computable.  Contradiction.

Now the question is how do we construct $M^B$?

Comment: It'd help to include the statement of the incompleteness theorem you want to prove and clarify which facts about computability and the busy beaver function you can use. The proof depends a lot on these choices.